# Program is not continuing after first portion of code

Tags: python, file, printing, break

Why is the code below stopping after 'break'? If I insert a print statement after 'break' it will print (e.g. print "done!"). Why won't it run the with open.. after 'break'? they each work separately on their own (as separate .py files).

```
diskDetails = open("diskDetails.txt", "r")
data = open("data.txt", "w")
searchlines = diskDetails.readlines()
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "Failed" in line:
        for l in searchlines[i-3:i+25]: print >> data, l
        print
        break

with open('data.txt') as infile, open('dataFinal.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith(("ID", "State", "Capacity", "Product ID", "----")):
            outfile.write(line)
```

The dataFinal.txt file is blank, so it appears to stop after the 'break'. Doesn't 'break' just stop the 'if' loop? Why will it do a print "Done!" but not the 'with open('data.txt').... part?

diskDetails.txt contains several records, each are 27 lines lines long (i've shortened for this sample):

```
ID                              : 0:1:6
Status                          : Non-Critical
Name                            : Physical Disk 0:1:6
State                           : Failed
Power Status                    : Spun Up
Bus Protocol                    : SAS
Media                           : HDD
Part of Cache Pool              : Not Applicable
Remaining Rated Write Endurance : Not Applicable
Failure Predicted               : Yes
Revision                        : ES66
Driver Version                  : Not Applicable
Model Number                    : Not Applicable
T10 PI Capable                  : No
Certified                       : Yes
```

The first part of the code gets the record that contains 'Failed' (finds failed and returns the 2 lines above (i-3) and the 25 below (i+25) and outputs it to a file named 'data.txt'.

The second part of the code (with open...) takes that data.txt file, looks up specific lines (containing ID, State, Capacity etc) and prints it to a file called dataFinal.txt

```
cat dataFinal.txt
ID                              : 0:1:6
State                           : Failed
Capacity                        : 558.38 GB (599550590976 bytes)
Product ID                      : ST3600057SS
```

These two parts of the code work fine independently (as shown above). How can I get them to work together in the same .py file? 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some data from the text files `diskDetails.txt` and `"data.txt"`  to reproduce your problem? You could try to close the files `diskDetails.close()` and `data.close()` before you open the file again.

Comment: Hi Darius, I've updated with your request. Thanks!!

Comment: I got an exception by executing your original code: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/darius/repos/stackoverflow/questions/54499774.py", line 6, in <module>
    for l in searchlines[i-3:i+25]: print >> data, l,
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'builtin_function_or_method' and '_io.TextIOWrapper'. Did you mean "print(<message>, file=<output_stream>)"?```

Comment: I accidentally had a ',' at the end of print >> data, l,  I removed the comma at the end and updated the code.

Comment: When you open 'data.txt' in write mode in second line, you truncate it and then when you open it in read mode after the break and try to iterate over it, there is nothing to iterate, hence your dataFinal.txt is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, finally I broke your code into three parts:

```
result = []

# 1. Search for the first failed entry:
with open('diskDetails.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
        if ': Failed' in line:
            result = lines[idx-3:idx+12]  # save lines from 'ID' to 'Certified'
            break  # only the first match

# 2. Filter result:
keywords = ('ID', 'State', 'Capacity', 'Product ID')
result = list(filter(lambda l: str(l).startswith(keywords), result))

# 3. Save result:
with open('dataFinal.txt', 'wt') as f:
    f.writelines(result)

# $ cat dataFinal.txt 
# ID                              : 0:1:6
# State                           : Failed
```

Comment: That worked! Now I know that I can break things down even more as well. Thanks Darius!

Comment: Darius Morawiec , How can I get step #1 to do that for multiple matches? For example, two records out of eight (in the file) show 'Failed'. How can I get it to do result = lines[idx-3:idx+12] for both?